# ng-show/hide not working after successful Firebase login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-authentication, ng-show, ng-hide

I have an issue with ng-show/hide not working after a successful Firebase login. I have a loggedIn variable in $rootScope as follows:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    console.log("loggedIn", $rootScope.loggedIn);
});
```

And have injected $rootScope in my login controller like so:

```
app.controller("loginCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseObject', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseObject){....
```

With that in place I have tested two login functions. The first is a dummy and doesn't actually go through the Firebase auth process but does show/hide the relevant elements in the view.

The second goes through the `Firebase auth` fine and even logs the `$rootScope.loggedIn = true` exactly the same as the first dummy function. But the `show/hide` doesn't work.

```
        // This works
        $scope.logIn = function(){
                $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                console.log("loggedIn", $rootScope.loggedIn);
        }

        // This doesn't work
        // logs into Firebase fine but ng-show/hide doesn't work
        $scope.logIn = function(){
            ref.authWithPassword({
                  email    : $scope.user.email,
                  password : $scope.user.password
                }, 
                function(error, authData) {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                  } else {
                    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                    // NEED TO FIX!!!
                    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                    console.log("loggedIn", $rootScope.loggedIn);
                  }

            });
        }
```

Here is the ng-show/hide in the HTML

```
<div class="login" ng-hide="loggedIn" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <form class="form-signin">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="user.email" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" required>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="logIn()">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    </div><!-- ./login form -->

  <!-- main page container -->
    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div class="main-content" ng-show="loggedIn">
            <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
            <hr>
            <div id="successNotice" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" ng-show="savedSuccess">
                Musician saved successfully!
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <label>Enter the name of your favourite musician</label>
                        <br>
                        <th>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="dev.firstName" name="firstName">
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="dev.lastName" name="lastName">
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="add(dev)"></span>
                            </button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="musician in musicians">
                        <td>{{ musician.firstName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ musician.lastName }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove($index)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div><!-- ./main-content -->
```

I know it's probably not the best or most secure way of performing this task and there should be more separation and fancy routing going on. But I just wanted to test it out as proof of concept before refactoring the business logic using better Angular practices. For the moment I'd like to know why this doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to expose `$rootScope.loggedIn` to your `$scope` because (I could be wrong) I'm pretty sure $rootScope variables aren't exposed to your HTML/template. `$rootScope` is available to your controller because you injected it, but only the `$scope` is exposed to your HTML so you need to manipulate the `$scope` variable.

Try adding this in your controller:

```
$scope.loggedIn = $rootScope.loggedIn
```

The `$scope.loggedIn` variable will be exposed to the HTML where it can be used by your `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.  Here, we're just copying the value from `$rootScope.loggedIn`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. In any case I am sure that `$rootScope` is accessible to the view because it works like a charm in my dummy `login` function in my code without needing to be saved into a new `$scope` variable inside the controller. Correct me if I am wrong, but Is that not what `$rootScope` is for? Allowing global states to be captured from anywhere in the app regardless of which view or controller is being used? Thanks for the response!